# Table Text Box Does Not Expand Once The Box Fills Up

Tags: html, css, forms, textbox, expand

I have a text box within a table that is populated by a form on my website. This text box can also be edited/deleted and I'm having issues displaying the full text onto the text box from the form the user fills out. The issue is that the text box does not expand to fit text that the user inputs. It will display the message all the way to the end of the text box and anything after that will not be displayed as the text box does not expand.

My code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <form action=findGroup.php method=post>
    <tr>
      <td><input type=text name=name value="John Doe" /> </td>
      <td><input type=text name=description value="Column width does not automatically adjust itself to fit content" /></td>
      <td><input type=hidden name=hidden value="" /></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=update value="update" /></td>
      <td><input type=submit name=delete value="delete" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: centre;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: centre;
}

th {
  text-align: centre;
  background-color: #4D5960;
  color: white;
}

tr {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/30u7wtn6/6/

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. Try editing your question, remove all the php script and replace your php outputs with dummy text. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/owv0eb7u/6/  . This would help getting answers.

Comment: @bdalina Thanks, this works to an extent but the box still does not expand when the test gets long  :(

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my code :)

Comment: Input field has it's limitation. Do you mind using jquery?

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Oh alright, and yes I'm open to using jquery if that can resolve it :) Would you be able to help me out with that as I'm not so good with JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Input field has it's limitation. So you can use contenteditable div to mimic an input field and copy the content from this div to the hidden input:

```
<?php
    if (!EMPTY($_POST)) {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table {
  width: 100%;
  font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: centre;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: centre;
}

.input {
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

th {
  text-align: centre;
  background-color: #4D5960;
  color: white;
}

tr {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- hide your input field with type hidden -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Fetch you php value here" />
                    <!-- create div contenteditable with id same as the input name -->
                    <div class="input" contenteditable id="name">Fetch you php value here again
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- same as example above -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Column width does not automatically adjust itself to fit content"/>
                    <div class="input" contenteditable id="description">Column width does not automatically adjust itself to fit content
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="some value" />
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="update" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

  // stop the form from being submitted
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var form = $(this);
    // find div with class name input and get their ids and text content
    $('.input').each(function(){
    // get the id from div
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
        // remove linebreak and trim excessive spaces
    var value = $(this).text().replace('/\n/g', " ").replace('/\s+/g', " ");
        // insert value to respective input name
    $('input[name="' + name + '"]').val(value);
  });
    // submit the form
    $(form)[0].submit();
});
</script>
```

Note: The above is just a sample and will post data to the same php file which you will have to change that to: action="**findGroup.php**" after testing.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/owv0eb7u/

Comment: Thank you dude, I'm struggling to incorporate your code above into my project though, any chance you could help me out with that? If so my code is here (PHP code is also within the HTML box), really appreciate the help!: https://jsfiddle.net/HasanK/x6wdaqej/

Comment: Try harder. If you still have difficulty,come back tomorrow and I will give it a try coz it's mid night in my place

Comment: Ok, no problem :)

Comment: Also, while you are trying, please don't use removed mysql_ extension. And use mysqli with prepared statement instead to prevent sql injection:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Really struggling on this one dude :(